# Internal relative links in Menu by using http:/alias/path/to/link

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

In Drupal 7.22, I would like to link create an additional link to an existing node from with in a menu. This target node already has an alias and its own menu entry. I'd like to create an additional link to that node. I thought the method would be to enter the url as `http:/alias/path/to/link`. However, this seems to fail.

If you notice from the devel_themer output that the `path` contains `http:/contact`. My hope that this link resolves to `http://mysite/contact`.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `node/123` instead of `http:/alias/path/to/link`?

Comment: Yes. That will overwrite node/123's existing menu entry. I'm looking to create an additional menu item pointing to node/123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module better jump menu seems to have been causing the issue. For any link such as `http:/contact` it stripped the http. I disabled the module and things worked as they did before.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go to **/admin/structure/menu**, select the menu you wish to add the link to, and list links. At the top select *Add link* and enter the title and link. You can use either the alias or system path. Then on the list, place the new menu item where you want it. It should not overwrite the existing menu entry.

Do not prefix the links with http:.

Comment: By doing this, it replaces the node's existing menu entry.

Comment: I just tested it and it is possible to have multiple menu entries all pointing to the same page even if the link is placed in a different place in the same menu. It does not overwrite the link defined in the node edit page. If you are seeing this, the problem is elsewhere. Do you have any menu-related contributed modules enabled?

Comment: I guess I'm trying to specifically control where the active-trail classes are applied. I'm looking for a solution to jump to that page to a different part of a menu tree. (I hope that made sense)